# Two hr's on the same line with space in between

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

[image: design]

So I've been given the above design and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the 2 lines below the WHO WE ARE text my first coding instinct is to put two hr tags on the same line and here's what I've got so far:

```css
.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.who-we-are{
  background-color: #19A1B9;
  background: #4A9FB6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="who-we-are">
  <div class="container center text-white">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
      <hr>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A itaque quod et, veniam vitae, amet, velit maiores molestias ipsa quia ipsam eveniet, eaque aspernatur. Qui maxime, voluptate totam. Ipsum, doloribus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll change it to the correct font etc... later on.

I'm not sure how to approach this in terms of CSS and a google search just made me even more confused.

Comment: It would make more sense to have one `hr` and style it to look the way you want.

Comment: How would you split the hr into two parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break in an HTML page (e.g. a shift of topic).

Since you need those lines for styling purposes, is more semantically correct to have a couple of `div`s with a bottom border and `display: inline-block` to be next to each other:

```
.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: white 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

You'll also just need a couple of rules to center them.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested on the actual website and works perfectly even on mobile which is good since I hate writing media queries

Comment: I agree except for the part where two divs are semantically more correct. If anything, the header should be the thing with the bottom border, although not sure if there's an easy way to achieve the two line effect on a border.

Comment: `<div>` is semantically meaningless, it adds no context and should be used mostly for styling. Those lines are also for styling purposes, they don't add any context to the content for any bot or screen reader to take. 
I agree that they could be part of the heading if that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to but those two hr's in a seperate div and set them inline block.

```css
.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.who-we-are{
  background-color: #19A1B9;
  background: #4A9FB6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.seperator {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="who-we-are">
  <div class="container center text-white">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr class="seperator left">
      <hr class="seperator right">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A itaque quod et, veniam vitae, amet, velit maiores molestias ipsa quia ipsam eveniet, eaque aspernatur. Qui maxime, voluptate totam. Ipsum, doloribus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that all do it, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The lines are decorative. You don't need to put them in the HTML.

Use CSS [**pseudo-elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and flex properties.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title > h1 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.title::before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  order: 1;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.title::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  order: 2;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.who-we-are {
  background-color: #19A1B9;
  background: #4A9FB6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="who-we-are">
  <div class="container center text-white">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A itaque quod et, veniam vitae, amet, velit maiores molestias ipsa quia ipsam eveniet, eaque aspernatur. Qui maxime, voluptate totam. Ipsum, doloribus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HR is a block level element therefore it will take full width. You have two options that I can think of. Make 2 divs side-by-side, make a table of 2 columns

2 DIVs:

```
<div class="hr"><hr></div>
<div class="hr"><hr></div>

<style>
.hr{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
</style>
```

And here is a table:

```
<table class="hrTable">
  <tr>
    <td><hr></td>
    <td><hr></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
   .hrTable{width:100%}
   .hrTable td{width:50%; padding:20px 50px; }
</style>
```

Here is a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfm56nta/) with both examples

Answer (score -1):

```css
.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.who-we-are{
  background-color: #19A1B9;
  background: #4A9FB6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.seperator {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="who-we-are">
  <div class="container center text-white">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>WHO WE ARE</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr class="seperator left">
      <hr class="seperator right">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A itaque quod et, veniam vitae, amet, velit maiores molestias ipsa quia ipsam eveniet, eaque aspernatur. Qui maxime, voluptate totam. Ipsum, doloribus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit your answer to add what the issue was and an explanation of your solution?